# AngularJS - Best practice for data tables

Tags: angularjs

I have a table containing 300 rows (limited), of 20 columns. - With Ag-Grid

This table also has 8 filters, each is a multi-select of average 50 rows. - With isteven multi-select

This module is very very slow, and Batarang shows ranging 7000 to in times 20000 $$watchers. This module is also the most important in the system.

I changed the filters to load dynamically at need, but still it is very very slow. (On Chrome, with 8 cores i7, and 16GB RAM)

What is the best practice for tables showing mass data?

Comment: Have you heard of Pagination?

Comment: A quick win for speedup can be to see where you can use one-time bindings with angular syntax {{::myVar}} https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: @Damiano Well yeah, but unfortunatly this is what my boss wants. only 300 out of the hundreds of thousands of rows.

Comment: Also, if you are using ng-show, you might be able to replace it with ng-if, which kills a lot of parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to looking in to a grid which uses virtualisation such as [`ui-grid`](http://ui-grid.info/), you can find an example with a large dataset [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/404_large_data_sets_and_performance)

Answer (score 3):

You can use one time data binding. In the view use `{{::myVal}}` instead `{{myVal}}` it should reduce number of watchers.

**[More](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html)**

You can do lazy rendering or virtual repeat to reduce number of DOM nodes you have to create. (which is your app bottleneck probably)

**[More](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat)**

Finally you can use your own implementation of angular compile method and use `$eval` to compile your own templates with `$scope` variables but without adding it to angular app scope. It can be much faster than angular solution because you can avoid all checks and optimize it for your app and render it as plain html without all angular magic which will make this bit much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. the main problem for me is that I cannot control the table itself (it is a directive I rather not change), I know of one time binding, but I cannot create my own table at this point, because this one has so many features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) for this. React's performance is much better. React is the `V` in `MVC` so you can use React + AngularJS.

You can also try this AngularJS library - [angular-datatables](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables)